# "." in a Rust module identifier

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, grpc, tonic

A question about gRPC codegen with tonic (uses protoc) under the hood.

The third party protos I am using are have package names like `thirdparty.specificpackage`, for example:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package thirdparty.common;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

service CommonService {
...
}
```

and a `build.rs` that looks like this:

```
tonic_build::configure()
        .protoc_arg("--experimental_allow_proto3_optional") // for older systems
        .build_client(true)
        .build_server(true)
        .out_dir("./src")
        .compile(
            &[
                "src/myprotoproject/protos/services/decision_engine.proto"],
            &["src"],
        )?;
```

the generated code from my `cargo build` is named `thirdparty.common.rs` - how do I import this into my Rust code?

`mod thirdparty.common` is not a valid Rust identifier because of the `.` - are there best practices around this?

Comment: `tonic::include_proto!` ?  https://docs.rs/tonic/latest/tonic/macro.include_proto.html

Comment: @jsejcksn Going to accept answer below since it is the most direct solution for posterity, but that post is linked to the "can you include a '.'" part of the question, so let's leave it linked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you cannot reasonably control or change the name of the file, you  can use a [path attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute):

```
#[path = "thirdparty.common.rs"]
mod thirdparty_common;
```